# what is the difference between inserting into ArrayAdapter and adding into arrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

i was working with ListView in android,so to insert items into the list with a button i did the following :created arraylist,arrayadapter,set the adapter to arraylist and used the following code :

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

this works fine but i also found that there is a method called `insert` for the `ArrayAdapter` so what is the difference between inserting into `ArrayAdapter` and adding into `arrayList` ?

PS :im new to this adapter concept can exlpain it to me ?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` is different than `ArrayList`

Firstly `Adapter` in Android is:

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the
>   underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data
>   items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item
>   in the data set.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) for details and types of `Adapters` in Android

And `ArrayAdapter` is:

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary
>   objects.

**But** `ArrayList` is:

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all
>   optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In
>   addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides
>   methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to
>   store the list. (This class is roughly equivalent to Vector, except
>   that it is unsynchronized.)

refer to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more info

**Also** read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561970/5993410) for more understanding about the difference between both of them

Comment: the other answer which you linked was helpful.if i understand it correctly there is a difference between `insert` into adapter and `add` to arraylist. so which one should i use ?

Comment: @anotherGatsby Have you understood the diffrence between `ArrayAdapter` and `ArrayList`? you can not compare two methods from two diffrent classes. Insert is used to insert objects in the Adapter's Array and add of the `ArrayList` is used to insert objects to the collection `ArrayList`

Comment: i think i'll try out the `insert` and `add` methods so that i'll know how they really differ.

Answer (score 2):

In simple understanding you can say that :

**arrayList** is used for items of the list while work of **arrayAdapter** is to manage the items of the list.

Rows are created on demand by the adapter as they come on to the screen.

I would recommend you to check out the link if you want to learn more about them
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html